# Golang - can I have a struct with slice member?

Tags: go

Is it possible to have a slice as a member of struct in Go? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything? show us some code..

Comment: I'm not sure what to even try. I don't see anything in the spec      that seems to make it possible - i []int is a slice, i [4]int isn't what I want.

Answer (score 8):

you can have a slice or you can have a fixed size array defined at runtime

package main

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    mystruct := struct {
        array [3]int
        slice [] int
    }{
        [...]int{1, 2, 3},
        []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    }
    fmt.Println(mystruct)
}
```

Comment: Right I get this, am I reading you right that it then isn't possible to define a struct type, which has an array whose length will be defined at runtime?

Comment: That is called a slice. A pointer to an array. The array can have any size you want. Is impossible to have the array inside the structure itself without and unknown size would make it impossible for the compiler to know how much memory to allocate for the type.

Comment: My understanding of a slice is that it's more than just a pointer to an array. Can I just have a pointer to an array in the type? Ie that would get around the problem of compiler not knowing how much memory to allocate for my struct type. Or is there simply no way to declare such a thing?

Comment: I suppose I'm looking for fixed capacity - I can just use a slice as you say and fix the capacity right.

Comment: Yes, `mystruct.slice = make([]int, 10)`

Comment: I don't think you can just have a pointer to an array. In Go, arrays have two defining attributes: type and size. You would need to declare a pointer to an array of 6 ints, for example, [6]int. That is, you need to declare both type and size for the pointer. It is much more idiomatic to use slices in general, and arrays for other uses like 3D points, pairs, etc.